# How can I make a retry function tail recursive?

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I have a discriminated union that is similar to the `Result` type used in [Scott's Railway Oriented Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/). For simplicity's sake, it's slightly simplified here:

```
type ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage of string

type ValidationResult<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Error of ErrorMessage
```

I have a corresponding module `ValidationResult` that contains functions that act on these `ValidationResult`s, one of them is a recursive `retryable` function that allows the parameter, `f: unit -> 'a`, to be called again (such as reading from `stdin`) if the `ValidationResult` is `Error`:

```
module ValidationResult

    let doubleMap success error = function
         | Success x -> success x
         | Error e -> error e

    let rec retryable errorHandler f =
        let result = f ()
        let retry e =
            errorHandler e
            retryable errorHandler f
        doubleMap id retry result
```

But it isn't tail recursive and I would like to convert it to be so. How can I do that?

Comment: AFAIK, the function is tail-recursive as it is, but the compiler does not compile it into a loop because it uses a nested function - so you need to enable "Tail calls" in the project options - that way, it will generate .NET code with actual tailcall instructions.

Comment: But if you're running on Windows or .NET Core, the JIT doesn't even need actual tailcall instructions, it will optimize tail calls anyway.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I thought if I decompile my code into C# and see a `while (true)` loop, that means my code is tail recursive, which doesn't happen in my `doubleMap` version

Comment: @rexcfnghk I added some more details in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F# compiler compiles tail-recursive functions in two different ways.

1. If the function is simple (calls itself directly), then it is compiled into a loop
2. If the tail-recursion involves multiple different functions (or even function values), then the compiler uses the `.tail` IL instruction to do a tail-call. This is also a tail-call, but handled by the .NET runtime rather than eliminated by the F# compiler.

In your case, the `retryable` function *is* already tail-recursive, but it is the second kind. Daniel's answer makes it simple enough so that it becomes the first kind.

However, you can keep the function as you have it and it will be tail-recursive. The only thing to note is that the compiler does not generate the `.tail` instruction by default in Debug mode (as it messes up the call stack) and so you need to enable it explicitly (in project options, check "Generate tail calls").

Comment: Very useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the call to `doubleMap` should do it:

```
let rec retryable errorHandler f =
    match f() with
    | Success x -> x
    | Error e ->
        errorHandler e
        retryable errorHandler f
```

Comment: Just curious, is there any way to keep the call to `doubleMap` while still making it tail recursive?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but, according to Tomas, it should be tail recursive as-is. Did you try it with a Release build? Tails calls are disabled by default in debug builds.

Comment: IMO, it's easier to understand without the inner functions.

Comment: I thought if I decompile my code into C# and see a `while (true)` loop, that means my code is tail recursive, which doesn't happen in my `doubleMap` version